# javascript fixed positioning issue with Ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, positioning, fixed

Hi this is my first question here and I hope that I will get help and that the answer will be helpfull to someone else also.

I have to position a header div element at the top at the page so it stays fixed as the body content scrolls under it. It all works well on desktop and on iPad 2 but when I test on iPad 1 in Safari it acts weird. At first you cvan scroll the whole page like there is no definition for the header to be fixed but at the second scroll the header stays fixed. I am using a css definition for fixedc positioning and also thisw jQuery hack that I have read it's usefull...

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if(navigator.platform == 'iPad' || navigator.platform == 'iPhone' || navigator.platform == 'iPod')
{
$("#fixed").css("position", "static");
};
});
</script>`
```

This is the URL of the actuall site...

`http://176.9.5.243/~marin/iQabinet`

Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 0):

the position fixed css feature only support iOS version >= 5.x

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Koo is right that position fixed is only supported in later versions of iOS, but there's also another problem: JavaScript is 'paused' whilst the user is scrolling on the iPad, making functionality based on scroll or scroll position a problem.

As soon as the user starts to scroll or holds their finger down on scroll the JS will stop. It will only restart once the scroll is completely finished. The script will then run and stuff will jump around all at once. Hope that helps.